# Navigation to specific viewcontroller in Storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, storyboard, push-notification

I have the following hierarchy in Storyboard

Tab Bar Controller >> Navigation Controller >> Players View Controller (Table View Controller) >> Player Details View Controller.

All navigation is done in storyboards using relationships / segues. Delegates are used for backward navigation.

I want to open Players detail view controller when a push notification is received. Also if any other view controllers are in top of hierarchy, I want to remove all views before showing players detail view controller.

Is it possible to navigate using the above scenario. Any help will be highly appreciated. Reply for any clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the segue from storyboard, we can use the old way to manually push to `PlayerDetailsViewController`, like this:

```
PlayerDetailsViewController *playersDetailsViewController = [yourStoryboardInstance instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayerDetailsViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:playersDetailsViewController animated:YES];
```

Whenever the push nitification coming, just call the method above to manually push.